# I'm stuck with a java-script question. Can you help me out?

Tags: javascript

[the inputs are there[theoutput is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeL8f.png)Christmas Eve is almost upon us, so naturally we need to prepare some milk and cookies for Santa! Create a function that accepts a Date object and returns true if it's Christmas Eve (December 24th) and false otherwise. Keep in mind JavaScript's Date month is 0 based, meaning December is the 11th month while January is 0.
my answer:

```
function timeForMilkAndCookies(date) {
    var month=11;
    var day=24;
    if(date=("year, "+ month +", "+ day)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
        
}
```

this was my code, but my code is not giving the correct output  when the inputs are false, it still showing true.

Comment: Side note, in JS `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: `=` is assignment, not equality.

Comment: The function argument is the Date _object_, and you're treating it as a string. I recommend consulting MDN (which is very often quite a good solution). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

```
return date instanceof Date && date.getMonth() === 11 && date.getDate() === 24;
```

first make sure the object you are given a date object, this is what `date instanceof Date` checks for.
Then ask this object its month and day and check that it matches what you want, namely the 24th day and the 11th month.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to use destructuring and conditionals. For example, if you build a function accepting a Date object as a parameter, you can destructure the month and day out of the passed in argument. Then, you can create a conditional to compare that day to christmas eve:

```js
function timeForMilkAndCookies(date) {
       // Destructure month and day from the passed in argument.
    const [month, day] = [date.getMonth(), date.getDate()]; 
    
    // if the day matches xmas eve, return true, else return false.
    if(month === 11 && day === 24) return true; 
    else return false;      
}
```